# Convert Matplotlib embedding in tkinter code from defs to a class

Tags: python-3.x, class, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to convert some code from the matplotlib documentation site that embeds a matplotlib graph into tkinter from a module containing defs into a module containing a class. This code is taken directly from matplotlib (https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html) and works exactly as expected. However for my purposes I need this in the format of a class rather than a grouping of defs within a module. Here is the original matplotlib code:

```
import tkinter

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import numpy as np


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, 
expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
toolbar.update()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, 
expand=1)


def on_key_press(event):
    print("you pressed {}".format(event.key))
    key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)


canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", on_key_press)


def _quit():
    root.quit()     # stops mainloop
    root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent
                    # Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL 
tstate


button = tkinter.Button(master=root, text="Quit", command=_quit)
button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

tkinter.mainloop()
# If you put root.destroy() here, it will cause an error if the window 
# is closed with the window manager.
```

It is easy enough to convert the figure creation portion of this code into a class, but I am unable to figure out how to get the on_key_press and the toolbar sections to code properly.

This is my class code, which creates the plot but all my attempts at adding the toolbar and having key presses work have failed.

```
class matplotlibAsClass:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.create_chart()
        self.frame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

    def create_chart(self):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
        t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
        fig.add_subplot(111).plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self.master)  
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    matplotlibAsClass(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Any help on how to convert the full matplotlib code, where the key presses and the toolbar works, into a fully functioning class would be greatly appreciated.

Here is code I have written that does not work:
The following code has been corrected and now works properly.

```
class matplotlibAsClass:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.create_chart()
        self.frame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

    def create_chart(self):
        self.master.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")

        fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
        t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
        fig.add_subplot(111).plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self.master)  
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", self.on_key_press)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self.master)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)


        self.button = Button(self.master, text="Quit",command=self._quit)
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def on_key_press(event):
        print("you pressed {}".format(event.key))
        key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)

    def _quit(self):
        self.master.quit()  # stops mainloop
        #self.master.destroy() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
        root = Tk()
        matplotlibAsClass(root)
        root.mainloop()
```

when I run this code I get the following error:

```
File 
"/Users/Me/Mee/python_db_programs/simpletestgui_sc_two.py", 
line 104, in create_stockchart
    canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", on_key_press)
NameError: name 'on_key_press' is not defined
```

After changing the on_key_press to self.on_key_press I get the following error:

```
File "/Users/Me/Mee/python_db_programs/simpletestgui_sc_two.py", line 
111, in create_stockchart
    self.button = Button(self.master, 
    text="Quit",command=self._quit())
TypeError: _quit() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

After correcting the def _quit() to def _quit(self) I get the following error:

```
File 
"/Users/Me/Mee/python_db_programs/simpletestgui_sc_two.py", 
line 111, in create_stockchart
    self.button = Button(self.master, text="Quit", 
command=self._quit())

_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "button" command: application has been 
destroyed
```

Based upon the previous error I commented out the self.master.destroy() portion of the def _quit and now the chart loads and the toolbar works but the quit button doesn't actually cause the widget to quit.

The final correction, which I didn't fully catch from a previous comment was to change command=self._quit() to command=self._quit and now everything works correctly.

Comment: I suppose you want to show the code where it does not work as expected, because this should be straight forward and one cannot guess on possible reasons it fails for you.

Comment: The problem I am having is with handling events. It is not clear to me how to get a class to cope with event handlers.

Comment: So it seems you didn't store the button in a class variable (`self.button`). Also `_quit` is a method of the class, hence it would be `command=self._quit` instead of `command=_quit()`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the corrections. I made the changes but am receiving an error about the on_key_press def which I assume has to do with the event parameter.

Comment: Yep, because it's also `self.on_key_press`. Methods of a class are refered to via `self.` from within the class.

Comment: Thanks again for the correction. Now I am getting a TypeError

Comment: I just realized I needed to change the def _quit() to def _quit(self)

Comment: Correct. I didn't spot that. Mind the difference though, as commented above: `command=self._quit` instead of `command=_quit()`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Everything works correctly now. If you would like to copy and paste the corrected code into a new box I would be happy to mark it as the answer so that you get credit. If I mark my question as the answer then the system will give me the points. Thanks again.

Comment: You cannot get points for accepting your own answer. But you can write up your own answer anyways and receive points from others voting on it. (My motivation to answer questions here is not about points. And I don't feel this particular case is worth the effort.)

Comment: Understood, Thanks again